# Auto-updating version badges ("shields") for tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Some tag wikis for software packages, e.g. [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django), are updated with "current version" quips about what the current version is and when it was released. [Shields.io](http://shields.io/) provides these metadata badges found all over the place, so I figured [I'd replace the static text](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607538/75) like:

> Django's latest version is **1.9.7** and was released on the 4th of June 2016.

with:

> [image: PyPI]

`[![PyPI](https://img.shields.io/pypi/v/Django.svg?maxAge=432000&style=flat-square)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django)`

Is this on-balance good or bad? Should I replace more? [My edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12688452) got +3/-1, a small sampling of reviewers. Hopefully more people will weigh in here.

**Pros**

- Updates automatically
- Always up-to-date
- Less things to review

**Cons**

- Updates automatically
- Uncontrolled third party (they're used so many other places though...)
- Harder to get the [Research Assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1656/research-assistant) badge
- *(Python/PyPI specific)* `/pypi/v/<project>` returns pre-releases; I'm trying to fix that. If someone is looking at the SO tag-wiki for the current stable version, there are bigger problems.